# « Une variante » ou « un variant » du Covid ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, santé-et-médecine

En parlant des nouvel·les variant·es du Covid, est-ce que c’est « une variante » ou « un variant » ? Si je regarde dans [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/variant) pour une traduction du mot en anglais, il propose « une variante ». Ça semble aussi correspondre à ce que j’entends de quelques ami·es francophones. Par contre, les journaux semblent préférer « un variant », par exemple :

- [Après les Comores, le variant sud-africain frappe Mayotte et La Réunion](https://www.liberation.fr/france/2021/01/29/apres-les-comores-le-variant-sud-africain-frappe-mayotte-et-la-reunion_1818760/)
- [Covid: le variant anglais alarme dans les établissements scolaires](https://www.mediapart.fr/journal/france/090121/covid-le-variant-anglais-alarme-dans-les-etablissements-scolaires)
- [Variant du Covid-19 : pourquoi un virus très contagieux est plus dangereux qu’un virus très létal](https://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2021/01/11/variant-du-covid-19-pourquoi-un-virus-tres-contagieux-est-plus-dangereux-qu-un-virus-tres-letal_6065875_4355770.html)

Pourquoi y a-t-il cette incohérence ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***le variant*** est simplement un terme technique en biochimie:

> Substance qui dérive d'une substance originelle par mutation. ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/variant/81112))

Tandis que ***la variante*** a une signification beaucoup plus générale:

> Chose qui diffère légèrement d'une autre de la même espèce. ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/variante/81113))

Donc il y a une différence entre ***le variant*** (la mutation) du Covid et ***la variante*** (la sorte) du Covid. On peut avoir des ***variantes*** du même texte, par exemple, mais on ne peut pas avoir des ***variants*** d'un texte.

Answer (score 2):

En addition à la bonne réponse de fev, voici quelques réflexions.

***Variant*** est le terme le plus adapté quand on parle d'un virus au patrimoine génétique suffisamment distinct pour mériter cette appellation. Dans ce cas, en toute rigueur, on devrait d'ailleurs plutôt parler de *variant du* ***SARS-CoV-2***, mais dans l'esprit de la plupart d'entre nous, ***Covid-19*** est synonyme de coronavirus, donc désigne le virus.

Si on parle de la maladie appelée **Covid-19** (d'abord au masculin mais les prescripteurs poussent malheureusement le féminin), on pourrait aussi parler d'une ***variante du/de la Covid-19*** pour désigner une maladie légèrement différente. Pour l'instant, en dehors de la contagiosité, les variants semblent cependant provoquer la même maladie, pas une de ses variantes.

La confusion de genres qui frappe le mot **Covid-19** est peut-être elle aussi suffisamment contagieuse pour avoir contaminé variant(e), ce qui fait qu'on se retrouve aujourd'hui avec les dénominations suivantes :

- le variant du Covid-19;
- la variante du Covid-19;
- le variant de la Covid-19;
- la variante de la Covid-19;
- le variant du SARS-CoV-2;
- la variante du SARS-CoV-2.

Ça fait beaucoup, et je ne compte pourtant pas les variantes Sars-CoV-2, covid-19 et COVID-19...

Answer (score 0):

Il faut différencier, d'une côte, entre la maladie (la Covid, feminin ?) avec ses symptômes et complications et, de l'autre côté, l'agent causant cette  maladie, le virus Covid-19, aussi connu comme SARS-COV-2 (le Covid, masculin ?). Quand on parle des *variants* de virus, on sous-entend le nouveau virus, qui a acquis des mutations et des qualités assez différent des ses versions connues, mais n'est pas suffisamment différent pour le classifier comme une nouvelle espèce (le nouveau virus). Le terme technique (biologique) français dans ce cas est **la souche**.

[*La souche virale*](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Souche_(biologie))

> en microbiologie et en virologie, une souche est une variante génétique ou sous-type intraspécifique d'un micro-organisme (virus, bactérie, champignon par exemple)